# simple RoR forum to integrate into my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forum

Wanted to know if someone had a suggestion on code or maybe there's a plugin (!) which would allow very basic forum functionality that I can integrate into my application so that it is single sign-on?

Otherwise...maybe a tutorial on how to build one from scratch and I just leverage our existing authentication?

Thanks!

I looked at the following thread but no answer was selected so just checking:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549/what-is-good-forum-software-to-add-to-an-existing-rails-application

Hi, did more research, this so far seems to be the best, anyone had experience and a sample site I can check out?

http://github.com/radar/rboard/tree/master

Has anyone worked with this plugin?  http://github.com/bscofield/bagpipes/tree/master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility, which I have used in the way you describe, is Beast. It's simple but yet nice and functional. It doesn't integrate as a plugin, but it's not difficult to use it in your site and pass your user session to it.

(Use the newer version called AlteredBeast: http://github.com/courtenay/altered_beast/tree/master)

Comment: how is the integration? when I googled how people did single sign on...they said it was a bear!

Comment: I realized after I wrote that, that my implementation might not be applicable in your situation. The setups I have built all use http digest authentication (authenticating against an ldap db) that occurs before they reach the site. Then the apache HTTP_REMOTE_USER environment variable, set after the user is successfully authenticated, is used by the site to identify the user to each separate application on the site (ie, forums, blog, etc.), and to match it with their user account.

Answer (score 0):

That one probably is the best, definately the most active and up to date forum written in Rails. I believe Radar has an example on his [blog](http://forum.frozenplague.net) which you could check out. It could be integrated into your site using Rails Engines if you are using Rails 2.3 as that allows you to embed other rails apps into your own.